# Regularization scheme independence as a gauge redundancy?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, renormalization, regularization

Observables should not depend on the regularization scheme under some renormalization procedure. Is there some way to interpret this fact as a gauge redundancy? In particular, is there some group structure which relates one regularization scheme to another?

Comment: The renormalization group does what you are asking for, but there might be an even more general version of it.

Comment: That aspect of the renormalization group apparently was lost on me!